# Past continuous with until recently

Tags: adverbial-phrases, past-continuous, time-words

I saw this sentence

> Until recently I was playing in the Jerry spider gang. In fact I had been with them for 15 years we needed to stop

Is the first sentence correct grammatically , I find it strange to use past continuous with **until recently**, would it be better to use past simple as the action of playing with Jerry is completly finished.

Comment: Why do you see the past continuous tense as incompatable with completed actions? The action in the past continuous tense should be completed before the present moment.

Comment: so if it is completed we should use past simple !

Comment: but past continuous actions are also completed.